# comparing strings,iphone

Tags: iphone

i have 2 strings say string A and String B
i need to check if they both are eqaul or not,
so did this

```
if(a==b){
//they are equal
}
```

on console they both are showing same value say 'hey'.
but condition is not working for me.
is there any other condition to check if 2 strings are equal.

like there is on

```
if([A isEqualToString : @"equal"])
{
}
```

but this i cant fit string B in this condition, can i?/

suggestions are always appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by 'but this i cant fit string B in this condition, can i?'? You should very well be able to use NSString -isEqualToString.

Comment: my bad... got it running thanks anyway sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[A isEqualToString : B];
```

should work just fine.

When you do

```
if(a==b)...
```

you are not comparing the strings but the pointers. This means, it'll only return true if A is exactly the same string as B (with the same memory address). If they they are equal, but not the same (so, e.g. if you store @"string" in two different places in your memory), you'll get a 'false'.

Comment: thanks Phlibbo...got it workking i was using wrong syntax. thank a ton